# Common query parameter binding with angular ui router state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to define a state which matches for any url having a common query parameter.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {    // First state
        parent: 'base',
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: function($stateParams) {
            // some code
        },
    })
    .state('urlMap', {   // Second state
        url: '/:ctrl/:action',
        templateUrl: function($stateParams) {
            // some template code
        },
    })
    .state('overlay', {          // common state
        url: '*?overlayName',
        onEnter: function($stateParams) {
             // Do some stuff
        }
    })
```

My question is that, how should I define the common state that whenever I go to some URL's like: `#/?overlayName=auth` or `#/user/profile?overlayName=auth` and I can execute the code written inside the **onEnter** callback.

I also tried the **$urlMatcherFactory** for compilation.